# sheetJS number format issues - European number format

Tags: excel, numbers, sheetjs

I am trying to convert the float number to European formats.

I tried to assign a format like below but it's not converting properly.

works fine:

```
cell.z = "#,###,##0.00";
```

does not work:

```
cell.z = "#.###.##0,000"
cell.z = "# ### ##0,000";
```

If it is not possible can I at least declare decimal values as **comma (,)** separator?
Can you please provide some pointers?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Hi , Did you find a solution? I actually have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

We do not need to add any special format to the number. I solved the problem by converting it to a number (Not String), excel will open based on user settings. No additional development is required.